# Downloading many files in Python, high startup latency of server

Tags: python, multithreading, server, download, latency

I am downloading a large number of image data from USGS server, and the connect time (latency) for each file is rather long (15 minutes), but the files are rather small so it takes only seconds to download them, after I get a response from server. I am using multithreading to have hundreds of prompts download at the same time.

The server requires username and password as well. Is there a way I could have that connect time only once, instead of everytime I initiate the download?

Below is a sample code I have been using:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import time
from itertools import repeat
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def download_n_write(url):
    global index
    os.chdir(images_path)

    print("\x1b[f\x1b[J" + f'{url} starting')

    command = f"curl -O -b ~/.urs_cookies -c ~/.urs_cookies --max-time 1200 --connect-timeout 1200 -L -n {url} -s"
    pipe = os.system(command)

    if pipe == 0:
        print("\x1b[f\x1b[J" + f"{url} Downloaded.")
        index = index + 1
        print("\x5b[f\x5b[J",index,"/",lengths, "Downloaded")
        return url
    else:
        return "N/A"


def download_aster_data(list_path, direct, timeout = 60*5):
    global index
    index = 0

    # grab list of data
    urls = list(np.loadtxt(list_path, dtype=np.str))[:10]

    workers = 20
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
    outs = executor.map(download_n_write, urls)
```

Thank you,
Amir

Comment: How did you communicate with the server? Is it via API?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RodneyMandap I used Curl and command prompt, also updated with code snippet thanks.